# Is Farmville: On the Farm identical to the original Farmville?

Tags: farmville

So, back in the early days of Facebook Apps, there was Farmville.

However, it seems the URL was changed: Instead of [`https://apps.facebook.com/farmville`](https://apps.facebook.com/farmville), it is now [`https://apps.facebook.com/onthefarm`](https://apps.facebook.com/onthefarm).

From my experience, I recall that *Farmville: On The Farm* and the original *Farmville* look very similar, and have the same mechanics, but it seems that all save data have been "wiped".

I've also noticed that the [original game page](https://apps.facebook.com/farmville) does not exist any more.

### Are they the same game or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are the same game. For me, no data has been wiped.